# PEM File "CERTIFICATE" vs "PUBLIC KEY"

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate, public-key

I have a PEM file that looks like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

which I can convert to another PEM file using: `openssl x509 -in key.crt -pubkey -noout`. The new PEM file now looks like:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
...
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

my question is, what is the difference between these two files?

Comment: take a look in http://superuser.com/questions/620121/what-is-the-difference-between-a-certificate-and-a-key-with-respect-to-ssl

Answer (score 11):

One is a public cert, the other is a key.  As Federico stated in comments, [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/620121/what-is-the-difference-between-a-certificate-and-a-key-with-respect-to-ssl) addresses it pretty well.

That being said, what are you trying to do?